# LLD: How to Use –dll and –add-stdcall-alias Swiches

Tags: c++, linker, clang, llvm, lld

I tried to build a project using LLVM that is originally built using GCC, but I met some errors related to LLD when linking. It uses --dll and --add-stdcall-alias to the linker, but LLD can't recognize them. I'm not very familiar to LLVM, would someone tell me how to solve that problem? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I think I can't just remove those switches.